# If $\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n1_{[0,\:a)}(x_i)\to a$ for all $a$, can we conclude $\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^nf(x_i)\to\int_{[0,\:1)}f$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, riemann-integration, monte-carlo

Let $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq[0,1)$ with $$\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n1_{[0,\:a)}(x_i)\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}a\;\;\;\text{for all }a\in[0,1]\tag1$$ and $f:[0,1)\to\mathbb R$ be bounded and Borel measurable.

> Let $\lambda$ denote the Lebesgue measure on $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$. Under which additional assumption on $f$ can we show that $$\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^nf(x_i)\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\int_{[0,\:1)}f\:{\rm d}\lambda?\tag2$$

Since it shoulbe be possible that $x_n\in\mathbb Q$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$ and $g:=1_{\mathbb Q\cap[0,\:1)}$ is a possible choice for $f$ for which $$\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^ng(x_i)=1\ne0=\int_{[0,\:1)}g\:{\rm d}\lambda\;\;\;\text{for all }n\in\mathbb N\tag3,$$ we obvioulsy *need* to impose an additional assumption.

Unfortunately, I was able to "prove" the claim for genral $f$, but I absolutely don't see where I've made a mistake.

First of all, if $(2)$ is true for all $f$ satisfying $\left|f([0,1))\right|\in\mathbb N$, then the result should hold for all $f$. In fact, given $\varepsilon>0$, we can find Borel measurable $g_i:[0,1)\to\mathbb R$ with $\left|g_i([0,1))\right|\in\mathbb N$, $$|g_1|\le|f|\le|g_2|$$ and $$\left|f-g_i\right|<\varepsilon.$$ Now, \begin{equation}\begin{split}\int_{[0,\:1)}f\:{\rm d}\lambda-\varepsilon&<\int_{[0,\:1)}g_1\:{\rm d}\lambda\\&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^ng_1(x_i)\\&\le\liminf_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^nf(x_i)\\&\le\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^nf(x_i)\\&\le\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^ng_2(x_i)\\&=\int_{[0,\:1)}g_2\:{\rm d}\lambda\\&<\int_{[0,\:1)}f\:{\rm d}\lambda+\varepsilon.\end{split}\tag4\end{equation}

So, I guess we cannot show that $(2)$ holds for all $f$ satisfying $\left|f([0,1))\right|\in\mathbb N$. But what goes wrong? Noting that $$\mathcal B([0,1))=\sigma\left(\left\{[a,b):0\le a<b\le 1\right\}\right)\tag5$$ it is obviously enough to show $(2)$ for $f$ satisfying $$f=\sum_{j=1}^kf_j1_{[a_{i-1},\:a_i)}$$ for some $k\in\mathbb N$, $f_1,\ldots,f_k\in\mathbb R$ and $0=a_0<\cdots<a_k=1$. But $(1)$ obviously implies that $(2)$ holds for such $f$ ... So, what am I missing?

**EDIT**: Another possibility would be that it is *not* possible that $x_n\in\mathbb Q$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$, but while I have no example of such $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ at hand, I'm pretty sure that it can be constructed, but please let me know if this is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\Sigma$ denote the set of all simple, Lebesgue measurable functions on $[0,1)$. Let $\Sigma_0$ denote the set of all functions on $[0,1)$ of the form $$s=\sum_{j=1}^k f_j1_{[a_{j-1},a_j)},$$ where $k\in \mathbb{N}$, $f_1, \ldots, f_k\in \mathbb{R}$, and $0=a_0<\ldots <a_k=1$. Note that $\Sigma\neq \Sigma_0$.

You correctly state that your hypothesis implies that $$\lim_n \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n s(x_i)=\int s$$ for all $s\in \Sigma_0$.

You also state that for any $f$ (in $L_\infty$, say), you can find $g_1,g_2\in \Sigma$ (not $\Sigma_0$) such that $|g_1|\leqslant |f|\leqslant |g_2|$ and $|f(x)-g_i(x)|\leqslant \varepsilon$ for all $x\in [0,1)$. This is also correct.

But for an arbitrary $f\in L_\infty$, in general you cannot find such $g_1,g_2\in \Sigma_0$ to satisfy this property. Indeed, let $S=\{x_i:i\in \mathbb{N}\}$ and let $f=1_S$. Then for any $g_1,g_2\in \Sigma_0$ such that $g_1\leqslant f\leqslant g_2$, $g_1\leqslant 0$ and $g_2\geqslant 1$. Of course, this $f$ is a simple function, but it cannot be well-approximated by linear combinations of functions of the form $1_I$ , $I$ an interval.

So the problem is that while the conditions imply that $\lim_n \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n s(x_i)=\int s$ for special kinds of simple functions, it doesn't imply that this holds for all simple functions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The thing which I don't understand is: $\mathcal G:=\{[a,b):0\le a<b\le 1\}$ should be a $\cap$-stable generator of the Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal B([0,1))$. So, if the claim is true for all $\sigma(\mathcal G)$-measurable $f$ (which is precisely your set $\Sigma_0$), it should also be true for all $f\in\Sigma$ (by the monotone class theorem). So, what am I missing?

Comment: And once we have clarified why my argument above doesn't work: For which class of $f$ does the theorem hold? As mentioned above, it holds for all $\sigma(\mathcal G)$-measurable $f$, but can we characterize these $f$ somehow?

Comment: As you said, $\sigma(\mathcal{G})=\mathcal{B}([0,1))$. So the set of all $\sigma(\mathcal{G})$-measurable $f$ is **not** $\Sigma_0$. It's the set of all Borel measurable functions. I think that what you're saying is that if $\{A\subset [0,1): \lim_n \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n 1_A(x_i)=\int 1_A\}$ contains $\mathcal{G}$, it should contain all of $\sigma(\mathcal{G})=\mathcal{B}$, and therefore all Borel measurable, simple functions should have this property. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, the set $$\mathcal H:=\left\{A\subseteq[0,1): \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n1_A(x_i)=\int1_A\:{\rm d}\lambda\right\}$$ should be a monotone class containing the $\cap$-stable generator $\mathcal G$ of $\mathcal B([0,1))$. So, it should contain all Borel measurable $f:[0,1)\to\mathbb R$.

Comment: Why is this a monotone class?

Comment: Do you think it is not? It contains $[0,1)$ and it is closed under limits, isn't it?

Comment: It's not closed under taking limits. Suppose that the points $(x_i)_{i=1}^\infty$ are distinct. Let $A_k=\{x_1, \ldots, x_k\}$. Then $$\lim_n \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n 1_{A_k}(x_i)=\lim_n k/n=0=\int 1_{A_i}.$$  But if $A=\cup_{k=1}^\infty A_k$, $$\lim_n \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n 1_A(x_i)=1\neq \int 1_A.$$ 

This example will work even without the assumption that the points are distinct by a density argument.

Comment: Well, then that's exactly the point I was missing. Thank you!